# Email Alerts Not Sending

Tags: email-alert

Working on an a configuration that sends an email alert to the case owner when status is updated to "Replied"

Though, im not getting an email alerts to my inbox.

- I've checked that the Deliverability is set to all
- Email
  alert/templates are active
- Debug log says the email alerts were
  sent out
- Email Logs has some some P (permanent errors) but not sure
  how to find the problem

How can I find the reason behind the permanent errors?

[image: Debug Log]

[image: Email Log]

Comment: The `P - Permanent failure` means not delivered (but was sent). Can you get assistance from your IT team's mail server team.  I have seen use cases where the sample email had words in the subject/body that were interpreted as pornographic and was blocked by the mail server

Comment: Ahh I see, so the problem isn't within SF. Got it will reach out to the team! ty!